# is it possible to unzip z01,z02... without .zip?

Tags: zip, archiving, winzip

I have multiple z01,z02, but missing a zip file.

Is it still possible to unzip?

If not, is there any repair tool that you recommend?

Comment: one thread suggests for these z01 etc files, that while you should have the zip file, (this thread says you need it http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/282377-How-to-unpack-z01-z02-z03-etc-files )  if you don't have it then maybe 7z can still do it http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/microsoft-windows/threads/429164/how-to-join-.z01.z02.z03-extension-files  report back  Get 7z here http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: I got error from 7-zip =\

Comment: In zip format the very important part of the archive file is the end because it contains the list of contained files and pointers to them. Maybe you can try to concatenate the parts (`cat archive.z* >archive_cat.zip`) and try some of the tools if they will be able to do something with the concatenated file.